# Pass same argument to function twice

Tags: elm

In Elm, is there a higher-order function to transform a function that takes two arguments of the same type into a function that takes one argument and passes it as both arguments to the original function?

Such a function would have the following signature:

```
twiceTo: (a -> a -> b) -> (a -> b)
```

And it could be used to define, for example, these functions.

```
square = twiceTo (*)
tuplize = twiceTo (,)

square 4 -- returns 16
tuplize 1 -- returns (1, 1)
```

It would be easy to define the function as `twiceTo func a = func a a`, but does this function exist in the core library or any other libraries? And more importantly, is there a way to compose this function out of the higher-order helpers in the core libraries like `always`, `identity`, `>>`, `|>`, and friends?  It would be nice to use it inline without having to declare extra functions or use anonymous functions.

Answer (score 4):

Such a function is not in [Basics](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Basics).

You can express it inline with a lambda (`\x -> ...`):

```
square = (\f x -> f x x) (*)
```

... but then its clearer to just inline the first operand:

```
square x = x * x
```

I don't think there's a way to express `twice` using only the combinators of [Basics](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Basics), without the lambda.